# Is It possible to dequeue select SCSS @import partial during compilation?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, sass

Is there a way to remove or disable a SASS @include partial using a preceding variable or dequeue esque method prior to its loading?

I want to use a centralized stock copy of Bootstrap SASS & localized variable override files to build slightly customized CSS files. However, I want to be able to selectively disable unused partials from the stock bootstrap.scss file during the sass build much like using a sass default variable. Is there a way to prevent an @import partial from loading further down in the SASS build chain without editing the stock bootstrap.scss file?

Comment: Short answer: no. You'd have to edit the bootstrap.scss file anyway to include any variable you'd want affect the `@includes`. What is the end goal with this? I'm assuming that you would be using this in separate projects, so editing the stock bootstrap.scss file wouldn't necessarily be an issue.

Comment: The end goal is to be able to build multiple sites off of a common set of SASS partials without altering the original manifest.scss file. In my case, I have a group of bootstrap 4 websites that share a lot of common resources. I use gulp and a local variable.scss file to compile and optimize each site's CSS file from a centralized copy of Bootstrap scss files. I would like to manage the bootstrap partials that are loaded for each site without altering the bootstrap.scss file.